# Why negative positioning in tikz is not similar to positive?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (a) {a};
\node [right=1cm of a] {b};
\node [right=-1cm of a] {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Why `b` and `c` are not equally distanced from `a`? How can I fix it and see them equally distanced, while using the same syntax for `\node` commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`right` also defines the anchors used to place the nodes and that is not symmetrical. So use `left` if you want to go left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (a) {a};
\node [right=1cm of a] {b};
\node [right=-1cm of a] {c};
\draw[<->,red](a.east)--++(-1cm,0);
\draw[<->,red](a.east)--++(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (a) {a};
\node [right=1cm of a] {b};
\node [left=1cm of a] {c};
\draw[<->,red](a.west)--++(-1cm,0);
\draw[<->,red](a.east)--++(1cm,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    
        \node at (-1,0) (c)   {c};
        \node  at (0,0) (a)  {a};
        \node at (1,0) (b)  {b};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But note, that this won't place the nodes at the same distance like `right=1cm of x`, because your approach uses the `center` anchors of the nodes, while `right=y of x` uses the `right` anchors, as Ulrike's answer nicely illustrates.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I known. My approach was to put c and b at the same distance from a.